# Logitech Webcam C930e Driver issue (code 19) on Win 10 LTSB

Tags: windows-10, drivers, webcam, logitech-webcam

first time here.
Here is my problem: I just bought a Logitech C930E HD Webcam and I can't get it to work on my windows 10 LTSB: I'm getting a Code 19 Error:

"*Windows cannot start this hardware device because its configuration information (in the registry) is incomplete or damaged. To fix this problem you should uninstall and then reinstall the hardware device. (Code 19)*"

I have the feeling that the initial driver that the Device Manager downloaded from the internet through Windows Update either is bugged or wasn't installed correctly and using an older driver doesn't replace ALL the bugged 'recent' drivers.

I don't know if the fact that I'm using a LTSB Windows 10 edition (Ver 1607) changes anything.

Please see attached pictures and USBTree output.

[device manager1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eopA5.png) [Event 430](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8tAM.png) [Event 20001](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2Frs.png) [Event 20003](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0nQT.png)

What has been tried:
- change USB port
- rebooted
- tried the webcam on a macbook pro => OK
- install older driver (downloaded from internet)
- UpperFilters and LowerFilters Registry trick

**How can I fix this issue to make the webcam work?**

Thank you

Comment: Event 420 screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9HsW.png   
Device Details screen : https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lIdD.png    
USBtree screen : https://ufile.io/udu1b    
Windows info screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdcT5.pn

Comment: Edit your question...

Comment: For information only: there's a [firmware update](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/webcam-c930e-business/downloads) for your camera

Comment: @spike_66 yes, that only works if the webcam is detected... which is not the case here because of the issue...